# Working with vectors in matlab to form matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

The problem is this.  I'm taking *Intro to Computational Math*.  It's been interesting, but I'm struggling to understand the matlab language.  I've been a programmer for nearly 20 years, and this is the first time with a language that allows for working with arrays in this way.

As an introduction to the *error function* (named *erf* in MATLAB), we've fit a curve to the following polynomial

$$
p_4(t) = c_0 + c_1t + c_2t^2 + c_3t^3 + c_4t^4,t = \frac{k - 1}{10},k = 1,..,11
$$

Then, using that solve the linear system $\boldsymbol{A^TAc} = \boldsymbol{A^Ty}$.  Solving, then, for the coefficients is quite simple.  However, the homework isn't finished.  I was taught that polynomials, like this, aren't particularly well-suited for the error function.  So, the lesson asks further that we use the same data (i.e. $k=1,..,11$ and $t$) and fit to the curve:

$$
f(t) = c_0 + e^{t^2}(c_1 + c_2z + c_3z^2 + c_4z^3), z=\frac{1}{1+t}
$$

This is where I'm struggling.  My past programming experience isn't helping to solve this one well.  I have this current statement for MATLAB which doesn't produce errors, but it also produces 11x35 matrix which is far too large.

```
k = 1:11;
t = (k - 1)/10;
B = [ones(length(t), 1), exp(t'.^2), exp(t'.^2)*(1/(1 + t')), exp(t'.^2)*(1/(1 + t')).^2, exp(t'.^2)*(1/(1 + t')).^3]
```

I based my statement from the one I used to define the original polynomial:

```
A = [ones(length(t),1), t', t'.^2, t'.^3, t'.^4];
```

How should I define this matrix, $\boldsymbol{B}$ (an 11x5), for use in the linear system?

Comment: Have you tried *looking at your values*? This is a huge benefit of the REPL. Just type in `ones(length(t), 1)`, `exp(t'.^2)`, etc. and hit enter, then see if the value you're getting is the size you expect.

Comment: Actually what you probably need to do is `.*` instead of `*`. In MATLAB `*` is matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the term `1/(1 + t')`. Your `t'` is a vector, thus when you compute `1/(1 + t')`, you have an 'inverse' of this vector, that is a row. What you need is the element-wise inverse given by `1./(1 + t')`.

The code

```
k = 1:11;
t = (k - 1)/10;
B = [ones(length(t), 1),...
    exp(t'.^2),...
    exp(t'.^2).*(1./(1 + t')),...
    exp(t'.^2).*(1./(1 + t')).^2,...
    exp(t'.^2).*(1./(1 + t')).^3];
```

yields $B$ beeing $11 \times 5$.

PS: By the way, I hope you do `c=A\y` and not `c=inv(A'*A)*A'*y`.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I had thought it must be something like that.  However, MATLAB is very much a new language for me.  It's amazing to me that one may work with vectors (arrays really) as regular objects (e.g. a simple int or scalar).  However, it isn't second nature to me yet and I'm still getting used to it.